# How to close all the activemail msg windows automatically after saved in draft

Tags: c#, email

I am new to C# and trying to find a way to close windows after all new messages are saved in the draft folders.

I have the following code which does close all message windows, but at the same time, it shuts down the entire outlook.

I think there are two ways to resolve but don't know how to code...

1. close all active new message windows without shutting down outlook
2. relaunch outlook inbox after shutting down outlook.exe

   ```
           // now generate emails 

           Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
           Outlook.MailItem newMail = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

           newMail.Subject = subject_header;
           newMail.Recipients.Add(email_add[i]);
           newMail.Recipients.ResolveAll();

           newMail.Body = body;
           newMail.HTMLBody += summary_html;

           //Add attachment
           foreach (string attachment in attachments)
           {
               newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue);
           }



           newMail.Display(false);


           newMail.Save();

           oApp.Quit()
   ```